# AJAX onreadystatechange not working

Tags: javascript, ajax

this is my onreadystatechange code. everytime it runs, it prints sucesso on the screen, even having an IF that should make it print 'Sucesso. Redirecionando...';
pretty lost here :( tried to make a separated function, din't worked too.
xmlHTTP is set, it gets the return.

```
xmlHTTP.open('GET', url, true);
xmlHTTP.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (xmlHTTP.readyState == 4) {
        resposta = xmlHTTP.responseText;
        if (resposta == "sucesso") {
            status.innerHTML = 'Sucesso. Redirecionando...';
            setTimeout("location.href='central.php'",3000);
            return
        } else {
            status.innerHTML = resposta;
        }
    }
};
xmlHTTP.send(null);
```

Comment: Maybe the value in `resposta` has leading or trailing white spaces. Try `if (resposta.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/, '') == "sucesso")`.

Comment: still same problem. it have no spaces, neither before or after... :(

Comment: What's the result of `for (var r = [], i = 0, l = resposta.length; i < l; i++) { r.push(resposta.charCodeAt(i)) } alert(r.join(' '))`?

Comment: In Addition to comment of Felix, you can properbly make the result visble with alert(".."+ resposta+"..") . I had used it often to verify the result string.

Comment: Oh, I forgot it again, you have to set the `g` modifier: `/^\s+|\s+$/g` ... try again (damn you JavaScript string `replace` method!).

Comment: Found the error with alert('resposta')... it was printing <HTML><HEAD></HEAD><BODY>resposta</BODY></HTML> thx folks!

Comment: status was a document.getElementById('statuslogin');